# Take a table from a website using pd.read_html and turn into a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to take a table using pandas pd.read_html function from the website https://www.statbunker.com/competitions/FantasyFootballPlayersStats?comp_id=556

I have got as far as making the table into a list but when I try to change it to a Dataframe only the 5 outputs from the top line of the 620x20 table appears in the output.The code I have used is

```
BPL1617 = pd.read_html("https://www.statbunker.com/competitions/FantasyFootballPlayersStats?comp_id=556")
```

Then to convert to a dataframe I used`BPL20162017 = pd.DataFrame(BPL1617)` but the output is wrong.
I hope to later add new tables from this website and merge them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know where I am going wrong!

Comment: `df = pd.read_html(url)[0]` ?

Comment: Worked perfect silly me! Only started using pandas and python recently